# How to create a new object with an aggregated reference to an existing object?

Tags: bonita

I'm working with Bonita BPM 7.5 and in my contract I have defined an object with an aggregated relationship to another object (complex data), my problem starts when in UI designer I show a table of existing objects (aggregated object) to the user for select which object will be referenced by the new object. Do you have any clues to do that? In particular, to create a new object linked to an existing object in DB. In all cases I'm using BDM accesors.

Tahnks in advance.
Regards...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have isn't so much a data matching problem, BDM accessors are the right approach here. Rather the problem is in the visualization of the data for the tables.

Have you considered creating a custom ReST API endpoint to "flatten" the data from your aggregated table for presentation purposes?